# Table columns width and column spacing

Tags: tables

### Situation

I defined custom column types in order to manage column width and text alignment. I defined those column types as below:

`\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}`

### Issue

When using those custom column types, the sum of the width arguments cannot be equal to 1. Indeed, it does not take into account column spacing.

### Question

Is there a way to subtract the `tabcolsep` length from the length assigned in the `newcolumntype` declaration?

### Demo

[image: demo]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\linewidth}}

\begin{document}

% Overfull \hbox (12.0pt too wide)
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{1}}
  \toprule
  \lipsum[1] \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

% Manual unreliable fix
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{L{.97}}
  \toprule
  \lipsum[1] \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
p{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
```

Comment: As simple as that. I did not know how to define an expression. Thank you.